# FFmpeg - concat videos with different start times in filter-complex

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation

To compile a final video from multiple audio and video files with different start times, I got to the below command so far:

```
ffmpeg -i audio_1.flv -i audio_2.flv -i audio_3.flv -i audio_4.flv -i audio_5.flv -i video_1.flv -i video_2.flv -i video_3.flv -i video_4.flv -filter_complex \
"[0]adelay=9761[audio0];[1]adelay=183387[audio1];[2]adelay=694634[audio2];[3]adelay=740306[audio3];[4]adelay=775587[audio4];[audio0][audio1][audio2][audio3][audio4]amix=5[audios];\
[5]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+30.236/TB[video0];[6]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+201.314/TB[video1];[7]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+702.615/TB[video2];[8]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+921.682/TB[video3];[video0][video1][video2][video3]concat=n=4[videos]" -map [videos] -map [audios] -c:v h264 output.mp4
```

Apparently, the audio part would be compiled correctly with this section:

```
[0]adelay=9761[audio0];[1]adelay=183387[audio1];[2]adelay=694634[audio2];[3]adelay=740306[audio3];[4]adelay=775587[audio4];[audio0][audio1][audio2][audio3][audio4]amix=5[audios]
```

But for the video part, with this filter in the above command:

```
[5]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+30.236/TB[video0];[6]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+201.314/TB[video1];[7]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+702.615/TB[video2];[8]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+921.682/TB[video3];[video0][video1][video2][video3]concat=n=4[videos]
```

The final video isn't correct and has about triple times more length than all video segments accumulated. I tried `overlay` to combine videos with different start times, but it only works for 2 inputs, now for 3 or more input videos trying `concat`, but I got the `More than 1000 frames duplicated` message. I used `-vsync 2` to remove this message, But the video still got too long.

Comment: `setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+921.682/TB` adds offset of 921.682 seconds to the video timestamps. I am not sure, but I think FFmpeg duplicates the first frame multiple times to fill the 921.682 seconds time gap.

Comment: I suggest you to make a small experiment: create synthetic video files: `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1 -vcodec libx264 -crf 17 -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 10 video_1.flv` and `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi`... `video_2.flv`. Apply concat filter: `ffmpeg -y -i video_1.flv -i video_2.flv -filter_complex "[0]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+10/TB[video0];[1]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+1000/TB[video1];[video0][video1]concat=n=2[videos]" -map [videos] -c:v h264 output.mp4` and use FFprobe for analyzing the output: `ffprobe output.mp4 -show_frames`. The input is 20 frames, but the output is 1030 frames.